# Error: Property auth does not exist on type FirebaseApp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i have this firebase setup

```
import "firebase/auth"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
})
export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

and I'm getting a message back that 'property auth does not exist on type 'FirebaseApp'.
Someone help fix this

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firebase `V9.0.0+` installed then you can switch to compat libraries to continue using existing syntax:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

However, I'd highly recommend [upgrading to Modular Syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which has certain performance benefits. The modular syntax for the same would be:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const auth = getAuth(app)

export { auth }
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) has exmaples of V8 (name-spaced) and V9 (Modular) syntaxes.